# Several DownloadTasks sequentially

Tags: ios, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I have *n* tasks sending to a server. When I launch them by `[taskN resume]` they will launch parallelly but i want to launch them sequentially - if first task finish, other task will launch.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you are best using `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue`.

It manages a queue of tasks and each one is performed on a background thread.

By setting the queue to only have 1 concurrent operation it will queue them up like you want.

You should...

1. Create an `NSOperation` subclass that does your downloading. Make it do SYNCHRONOUS downloads. They don't need to be asynchronous as they will already be on a background thread.
2. Set up an `NSOperationQueue` and set `maximumNumberOfConcurrentOperations` to 1.
3. Add your operations to the queue.

This is the easiest way to approach `NSOperationQueue` but there are many more things that you can do with it.

There are also several questions and tutorials about it so I won't go into full detail here as you should be able to find other SO questions.

Answer (score 5):

I came with quite simple solution without subclassing:

Sample:

```
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];

    // first download task
    [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0); // create a semaphore


        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
        NSURLSessionTask *task1 = [session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {


            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore); // go to another task
        }];
        [task1 resume];
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); // wait to finish downloading

    }];
    // second download task
    [queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);


        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
        NSURLSessionTask *task2 = [session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {


            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
        }];
        [task2 resume];
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    }];
```

These two operations (task1, task2) will execute sequentially, so they will wait until *n-1* operation will finish.

Using semaphores inspired in [NSURLSession with NSBlockOperation and queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198404/nsurlsession-with-nsblockoperation-and-queues)