# Signalling notify only after all sync requests have completed

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Getting a notification when all async requests have completed.

I call `registerTrack` multiple times in the loop below. I want to only trigger the `syncGroup.notify` when ***all*** requests have been completed. From looking at this code, its going to `notify` after each successful completion of `registerTrack`. How do I make it signal `notify` only after all `registerTrack` operations have been completed?

My code is as follows:

```
    var fail = false
    let syncGroup = DispatchGroup() //used so we can determine if all the register requests have finished

    for track in unsyncedTracks {
        syncGroup.enter()

        if fail {
            syncGroup.leave()
            break //might save an aync request from getting executed on failure
        }

        registerTrack(track: track, withCompletion: { (success: Bool) -> () in

            if success {
                self.debug.log(tag: "RecordViewController", content: "Registered track: \(track.name)")
                syncGroup.leave()
            }
            else {
                fail = true
                syncGroup.leave()
            }
        })
    }

    //all requests complete
    syncGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        if fail {
            complete(false)
        }
        else {
            self.debug.log(tag: "RecordViewController", content: "Finished registering all unsynced tracks")
            complete(true)
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

Based on the recommendation to use GCD concurrent queues, I changed my code to:

```
    var failed = false
    //work item to loop through and call registerTrack on each track
    let registerTracksWorkItem = DispatchWorkItem {
        for track in unsyncedTracks {
            if failed { //exit early on failure, potentially save a network request
                break
            }

            self.registerTrack(track: track, withCompletion: { (success: Bool) -> () in

                if success {
                    self.debug.log(tag: "RecordViewController", content: "Registered track: \(track.name)")
                }
                else {
                    failed = true
                }
            })
        }
    }

    //handler for when all registerTrack calls are complete
    registerTracksWorkItem.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        if failed {
            self.debug.log(tag: "RecordViewController", content: "At least one registerTrack call failed")
            complete(false)
        }
        else {
            self.debug.log(tag: "RecordViewController", content: "Finished registering all unsynced tracks")
            complete(true)
        }
    }

    //execute the work item
    let queue = DispatchQueue.global()
    queue.async(execute: registerTracksWorkItem)
```

This code does not wait for `registerTrack` to finish, rather it executes them all and calls the `notify` event. :(

EDIT 3:

So this works. It uses a counter to check to see if its at the final `unsyncedTracks` object.

```
    var fail = false
    let syncGroup = DispatchGroup() //used so we can determine if all the register requests have finished

    //used to make sure notify is only triggered when all registerTracks are complete
    let unsyncedTracksCount = unsyncedTracks.count
    var completeCounter = 0

    syncGroup.enter()
    for track in unsyncedTracks {

        registerTrack(track: track, withCompletion: { (success: Bool) -> () in

            if success {
                self.debug.log(tag: "RecordViewController", content: "Registered track: \(track.name)")
            }
            else {
                fail = true
            }

            completeCounter = completeCounter + 1
            if completeCounter == unsyncedTracksCount {
                syncGroup.leave()
            }
        })
    }

    //all requests complete
    syncGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        if fail {
            complete(false)
        }
        else {
            self.debug.log(tag: "RecordViewController", content: "Finished registering all unsynced tracks")
            complete(true)
        }
    }
```

Can I do this (it also appears to work)? I added the if fail, `leave()` if.

```
    var fail = false
    let syncGroup = DispatchGroup() //used so we can determine if all the register requests have finished

    //used to make sure notify is only triggered when all registerTracks are complete
    let unsyncedTracksCount = unsyncedTracks.count
    var completeCounter = 0

    syncGroup.enter()
    for track in unsyncedTracks {
        if fail { //might save an aync request from getting executed on failure
            syncGroup.leave()
            break
        }

        registerTrack(track: track, withCompletion: { (success: Bool) -> () in

            if success {
                self.debug.log(tag: "RecordViewController", content: "Registered track: \(track.name)")
            }
            else {
                fail = true
            }

            completeCounter = completeCounter + 1
            if completeCounter == unsyncedTracksCount {
                syncGroup.leave()
            }
        })
    }

    //all requests complete
    syncGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        if fail {
            complete(false)
        }
        else {
            self.debug.log(tag: "RecordViewController", content: "Finished registering all unsynced tracks")
            complete(true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Putting multiple asynchonrous calls into a loop isn't good design. GCD's concurrent queues may be a good fit for your problem. That way you can run all the registerTracks tasks and know when they are all finished. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html

Comment: @Essenceofchicken have you got an example? thanks.

Comment: I Added a link above to the Apple documentation, theres code snippets in there.

Comment: @Essenceofchicken The samples are all in C++. Is there a Swift version somewhere, specifically similar to what I'm trying to do?

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1

Comment: @Essenceofchicken Do I wrap my `for track in unsyncedTracks` loop into a `async` closure? If I understand this right, it'll execute the closure asynchronously, which then executes all the `registerTrack` calls asynchoronously as well? If so, then how do I do the `notify` bit? I'm a bit confused on how to layout the code in my example

Comment: @Essenceofchicken See my updated post. I think I've implemented your suggestion, but its not waiting until completion now.

Comment: @toast, first of all, are you sure your `registerTrack()` function called the completion handler just once? Check it with logging or debugger. Second, in your first sample of code you call `break` between `.enter()` and `.leave()`, it's a straight road to more issues, you shouldn't break you loop between `.enter()` and `.leave()` without proper managing of the states of queue.

Comment: @dive #1 yes, `registerTrack` only calls the completion handler once, with a boolean value. #2 I updated the break, so now it does a `leave()` before the break.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem is related to your `fail` variable and `for` loop structure. You assign `fail` as `false` before the loop execution. When you code enters the loop and register `.enter()` then it checks for `if fail` condition and call `.leave()` if `fail` is `true`. Basically, when one of the call to `registerTrack()` sets the `fail` to `true` your code is in undetermined state, because `registerTrack()` is async and you don't know which of `.enter()` calls set the flag to `true`.
At the moment when `.enter()` count is equal to `.leave()` count (two fails in a row for example), CGD decides that your queue is finished and called `.notify()` "prematurely".

I suggest you to remove the flag `fail` (the code will work as expected, but will execute `registerTrack()` for all `unsyncedTracks`) and rethink your solution and logic. For example, `DispatchWorkItem.cancel()` can be a solution for your problem.

Comment: I've updated my answer, and the code is working as expected now.  The reason I had that `if fail` there was to exit prematurely, in the event of a failure, so it saves the phone from making another network call. While `syncGroup` may become unsycned (undertermined), does it matter, as its acting as a cancel all? Thanks.

Comment: Theoretically, it's possible to cancel the dispatched queue with `DispatchWorkItem.cancel()` or with `dispatch_cancel` handler, but you will be forced to handle the results and `dispatch_cancel` just cancel future execution of the block, but already dispatched blocks will be executed anyway.
I recommend you to rewrite your code using `OperationQueue` ([Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/operationqueue)), because it does exactly what you want and can be cancelled easily with `cancelAllOperations()`.

Comment: In the past, I have tried using NSOperations, but it doesn't work too well when you have a bunch of async requests. For example, say you make one a dependency on another, if it contains an async request, it will continuing executing, not waiting for the response. To be honest, I like the idea of these queues in swift, but none are really helpful to me. I would love to see an example of a few async requests together, one not being called until the other is complete. I wonder if I'm just implementing them poorly.

Comment: See this question where I attempted to use NSOperations for a similar problem. I ended up ditching the NSOperation stuff because it just didn't seem to suit this type of application. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39899105/waiting-for-request-to-finish-before-executing-the-next-operation