# Alamofire never calls encodingCompletion for upload with MultipartFormData when main thread is waiting for it to run

Tags: swift, asynchronous, concurrency, alamofire

I have code of this form:

```
func myFunction(<...>, completionHandler: (ResponseType) -> Void) {
    <prepare parameters>

    mySessionManager.upload(multipartFormData: someClosure,
        to: saveUrl, method: .post, headers: headers) { encodingResult in
          // encodingCompletion
          switch encodingResult {
                case .failure(let err):
                    completionHandler(.error(err))
                case .success(let request, _, _):
                    request.response(queue: self.asyncQueue) { response in
                        // upload completion
                        <extract result>
                        completionHandler(.success(result))
                    }
            }
     }
}
```

And testing code like this:

```
func testMyFunction() {
    <prepare parameters>

    var error: Error? = nil
    var result: MyResultType? = nil

    let sem = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    var ran = false
    myFunction(<...>) { response in
        if ran { 
            error = "ran twice"
            return
        }
        defer {
            ran = true
            sem.signal()
        }

        switch response {
            case .error(let err): error = err
            case .success(let res): result = res
        }
    }
    sem.wait()

    XCTAssertNil(error, "Did not want to see this error: \(error!)")

    <test response>
}
```

I use a semaphore to block the main thread until the request is processed asynchronously; this works fine for all my other Alamofire requests -- but not this one. The test hangs.
(Note bene: Using [active waiting](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1111#issuecomment-281480598) does not change things.)

Using the debugger, I figured out that

- all code that executes does so just fine but
- [`encodingCompletion` is never called](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/25d8fdd8a36f510a2bc4fe98289f367ec385d337/Source/SessionManager.swift#L715).

Now my best guess is that `DispatchQueue.main.async` says, "execute this on the main thread when it has time" -- which it never will, since my test code is blocking there (and will run further tests, anyway).

I replaced it with `self.queue.async` and `upload.delegate.queue.addOperation`, two other queueing operations found in the same function. Then the test runs through but yields unexpected errors; my guess is that then, `encodingCompletion` is called *too early*.

There are several questions to ask here; an answer to any can solve my problem.

1. Can I test such code differently so that `DispatchQueue.main` can get to other tasks?
2. How can I use the debugger to find out which thread runs when?
3. How can I adapt [Alamofire at the critical position](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/25d8fdd8a36f510a2bc4fe98289f367ec385d337/Source/SessionManager.swift#L715) so that it does not require the main queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should not block the main thread. XCTest has its own solution for waiting on asynchronous computations:

```
let expectation = self.expectation(description: "Operation should finish.")
operation(...) { response in
    ...
    expectation.fulfill()
}
waitForExpectations(timeout: self.timeout)
```

From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xctestcase/1500748-waitforexpectations):

> Runs the run loop while handling events until all expectations are fulfilled or the timeout is reached. Clients should not manipulate the run loop while using this API.

---

Outside of XCTest, we can use a similar mechanism as [XCTestCase.waitForExpectations()](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-xctest/blob/master/Sources/XCTest/Public/Asynchronous/XCTestCase+Asynchronous.swift) does:

```
var done = false
operation(...) { response in
    ...
    done = true
}

repeat {
    RunLoop.current.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.1))
} while !done
```

*Note:* This assumes that `operation` sends its work to the same queue itself is executed on. If it uses another queue, this won't work; but then the approach using `DispatchSemaphore` (see [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42644111/539599)) does not cause a deadlock and can be used.

The implementation in XCTest does a lot more (multiple expectations, timeout, configurable sleep interval, etc.) but this is the basic mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2007#issuecomment-287779727), this is a **bad "solution"** as it introduces the possibility for deadlocks when requests are nested. I'm leaving this here for instructional purposes.

---

Changing

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let encodingResult = MultipartFormDataEncodingResult.success(
            request: upload,
            streamingFromDisk: true,
            streamFileURL: fileURL
        )

    encodingCompletion?(encodingResult)
}
```

in [SessionManager.swift](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/25d8fdd8a36f510a2bc4fe98289f367ec385d337/Source/SessionManager.swift#L715) to

```
self.queue.sync {
    ...
}
```

solves (read: works around) the problem.

I have no idea if this is a robust fix or anything; I have [filed an issue](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2007).