# How to use JSON outside Alamofire.request()?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I trying return `JSON` Dictionary from `Alamofire`. The problem is that when assigning `JSON` to an external variable, the assigned value is saved and read only inside the `Alamofire.request` block, and outside its value is not saved (magic for me). What have I done wrong?

I do this first time. I'm tried use `URLSession.shared.dataTask` but I also could not return value from task.
I noticed that first the breakpoint triggered on the `return res` line, then on the `return json` line and then on the `print (JSON)` line. I do not know why.

```
struct resultMsg {
    var message: [String:Any] = [:]
    init() { }
    init(message: [String:Any]) {
        self.message = message
    }
}

func sendGET(method: String, data: [String:String]) -> [String:Any] {
    let resultURL: String = rootURI + method
    let url = URL(string: resultURL)!
    var res: [String:Any] = [:]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: data, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response)
            if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
                switch(status){
                case 201:
                    print("example success")
                default:
                    print("error with response status: \(status)")
                }
            }
            //to get JSON return value
            if let result = response.result.value {
                let JSON = result as! NSDictionary
                res = JSON as! [String : Any]
                print(JSON) // Here res is contain actualy json
            }
    }
    return res // Here res equal [:]
}

public func Authorize() -> resultMsg {
    let data: [String:String] = ["login":login,
                                 "pass":pass]        
    var json = resultMsg.init()
    json.message = sendGET(method: "auth.php", data: data)
    return json
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I decided that it was too early for me to write `Swift` programs. I wanted to port my project for iOS written in `C#`, I decided that the native application would be better, and there are so many pitfalls with these closure. But in `C#` everything is simpler: just write `await` before a function, but there it is not always needed.

Thanks to everyone who helped...

**UPD 1**

I know that this is probably stupid, but only this method works without unnecessary trouble with closures. But the repetitive code will become a lot.

**UPD 2**

Also unfortunately I had to use `GET` instead of `POST`, since in `POST` the server did not receive any data. I checked it with `echo json_encode($_POST);`. But I might as well not have used `Alamofire`.

**UPD 3**

Finally, I was achieved a better solution by Tom Harrington's advice. Before I found solution [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42484670/3485518), but it don't work in `DispatchQueue.main.async` like as `Alamofire.request`(I suggested that `Alamofire` uses `main.async`). Therefore, I did [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44026493/3485518).

**UPD 4**

And I'm wrong again. Solution in UPD 3 sometimes freezes in loop body. And I'm decided finally learn use own completion, and I did it :)

```
func sendGET(_ method: String,_ data: [String:String],_ instance: CommonClass, completion : @escaping (Any?)->()) {
    let url = getURL(method: method, data: data)
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseJSON { response in
        if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
            instance.manageStatus(status)
        }
        if let result = response.result.value {
            completion(result)
        }
    }
}

func someFunc(_ instance: CommonClass) {      
    let data: [String:String] = ["id":String(id),
                                 "route":route]
    sendGET("getTaskData.php", data, instance, completion: { response in
        let JSON = response as! [[String:String]]
        // Do something with JSON
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the network request is asynchronous, as they usually are. When you call `Alamofire.request(...)`, the network request starts, and `request` returns immediately. In the meantime, networking stuff happens in the background. Since `request` has returned, your `sendGET` function continues on to the next line immediately.

Later on, when the network request finishes, the completion block gets called. You assign the value to `res`, but it's too late because `sendGET` already returned an empty dictionary back when the request started.

Usually this is pretty fast, but it can help to imagine that it's going to take a very long time. Sometimes it **will** take a very long time, after all. If the network connection times out, it could take several minutes.

There are different ways of dealing with this.

- In one approach you'd make `res` a property of the class where this code is. Then your completion block would still assign a value to `res`, and then call some new code to tell your class that the result is available.
- In another approach, you would modify the completion closure to pass the JSON data to some other function that uses the data directly. Add some new function that has an argument of type `[String : Any]`, and call this function from the completion closure.

Which one is better depends on what else is going on in your app and how you need to use this data when you get it.

Answer (score 0):

Tom Harrington is right. The better approach would be add a completion block to

> func sendGET

like

```
func sendGET(method: String, data: [String:String], completion: ([String:Any]) -> Void)
```

and call the completion when you get the json, Thats it.

Happy coding

Comment: For your version, the compiler asks to add `@escaping`
    `func sendGET(method: String, data: [String:String], completion: @escaping ([String:Any]) -> Void)`

then I add in `sendGET`

    `completion(res)`

and in Authorize()

    `sendGET(method: "auth.php", data: data){ dict in`
    `json.message = dict`
    `}`

But break points triggered in same sequence

Answer (score 0):

I will offer you a method. With the help of Swift 4.2, [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) has been started, so you can easily JSON parse and get rid of the code.

Examples Class

```
public struct Faults: Decodable {

    public enum CodingKeys:String,CodingKey{
        case guid
        case adi
    }

    public let guid:Int
    public let adi:String
}
```

And json parse (get web services)

```
 public func fetchFaults(complation: @escaping (Result<[Faults]>) -> Void) {
        let urlString = "http://examples"
       request(urlString, method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: ...)
        .responseData { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                do {
                    let faults = try Decoders.plainDateDecoder.decode([Faults].self, from: data)
                    complation(.success(faults))
                } catch{
                    complation(.failure(Error.serializationError(internal: error)))
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                complation(.failure(Error.networkError(internal: error)))
            }
        }
    }
```