# Objective C - HTTP GET Request API

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsession

I've been trying to query Tesco's API Service. Although I've managed comfortably on Python with this, I have been having some trouble with making a request using Objective C. Nothing is being logged on the output. Any help would be appreciated. The program code is shown below:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultSessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:defaultSessionConfiguration];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dev.tescolabs.com/product/?gtin=4548736003446"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        NSString *postParams = @"subscription key=93a6e21eed2e4ca3a858a0f1fc5aaf03";
        NSData *postData = [postParams dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
        [urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

        NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Response: %@",response);
            NSLog(@"Data: %@",data);
            NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
        }];
        [dataTask resume];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you check the error in the completion handler?

Comment: Yeah I've just checked the error in the completion handler and nothing is logged. Also updated the URL and here's the source of the API: https://devportal.tescolabs.com/docs/services/

Comment: @Benge try error.localizedDescription

Comment: When you say nothing is being logged, do you mean the error is nil, or that the `NSLog`s are never executed?

Comment: NSLog's are not being executed. @ravi.p tried and no errors logged.

Comment: Maybe try a very different URL, e.g. Google to test.

Comment: @Benge are you looking for Grocery Search or Product Data ?

Comment: @ravi.p Product Data.

Answer (score 1):

I had no choice but to present an answer ... Notice the runloop code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultSessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:defaultSessionConfiguration];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dev.tescolabs.com/product/?gtin=4548736003446"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        NSString *postParams = @"subscription key=93a6e21eed2e4ca3a858a0f1fc5aaf03";
        NSData *postData = [postParams dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
        [urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

        __block BOOL done = NO;
        NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Response: %@",response);
            NSLog(@"Data: %@",data);
            NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
            done = YES;
        }];
        [dataTask resume];

        while (!done) {
            NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1];
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:date];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Best answer so far. The NSRunLoop works and finally got a response with that. Error is null and has status code of 500. Btw hide the details such as key. Thanks bud.

Comment: @Benge please read the docs, it says to assign the key as a header field, not in the post body. RTFM ;) https://devportal.tescolabs.com/docs/services/57f247f9e2813e07d8663943/operations/57f2518fe2813e07d8663945

Comment: Mazyod, changed it to the header fields. Thank you.

Comment: Status of OK and data is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need a run loop to perform a background task.

Your request does not work because the body `POST` data are not considered using a `GET` request.
All parameters must be passed in the URL.

To implement the run loop just use `CFRunLoopRun()` and `CFRunLoopStop()`.

**Do not use `NSRunLoop ... runUntilDate` with a while loop**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultSessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:defaultSessionConfiguration];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dev.tescolabs.com/product/? ... "];

        NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithURL: url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Response: %@",response);
            NSLog(@"Data: %@",data);
            NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
            CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }];
        [dataTask resume];
    }

    CFRunLoopRun();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, I really like your approach. But what's the real harm in a while loop with proper use of retain/release objects that won't collect garbage?

Comment: Same goes, why shouldn't you use NSRunLoop with a loop?

Comment: It does not harm. It's just an awkward and inefficient way.

Comment: @Benge Whenever you can avoid polling (this kind of loop), do it. *Don't ask, tell* or *Don't wait, notify*.

Comment: @Vadian, Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

`-dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:` is asynchronous. You are queuing up an action which would be completed later then exiting the program before it completes.

You need a mechanism to wait for the data task to complete before exiting the program.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34200617/1298400 for an example waiting mechanism.

Comment: I'm not so sure about using semaphores, since perhaps the callback is delivered on the main thread. Prefer to use `[NSRunLoop runUntilDate:]`

Comment: Yeah, the semaphores approach would in essence block the main thread.

Comment: @Mazyod Whatever method he uses, he has to block the main thread.

Comment: @JefferyThomas Nope .. Look into `NSRunLoop`

Comment: @Mazyod look at his code sample. He exits the main thread. That's it, program over. If he doesn't block the main thread, there will be no program running to execute his callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this u need to pass subscription key in header in this request

```
NSDictionary *headers = @{ @"ocp-apim-subscription-key": @"YourKey"};

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YourURL"]
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:10.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                if (error) {
                                                    NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                                } else {
                                                    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
                                                    NSLog(@"%@", httpResponse);
                                                }
                                            }];
[dataTask resume];
```

Comment: @chronikum Done

Comment: Very good approach, unfortunately I've still got no response at all within the output.

Comment: @Benge it is working properly so can u describe me what is the issue u r facing

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultSessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:defaultSessionConfiguration];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dev.tescolabs.com/product/? ... "];

        NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithURL: url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Response: %@",response);
            NSLog(@"Data: %@",data);
            NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
            CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }];
        [dataTask resume];
    }

    CFRunLoopRun();
    return 0;
}
```