# How to turn an asynchronous method into a synchronous method

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, semaphore, synchronous

I'm calling one method from another method.The method exits in the middile. After completing some tasks, it will run the remaining method.

```
-(void)stateMethod{
    [self.pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    lblTitle.text=@"State";
    self.stateTF.text=@"";
    self.stateTF.inputView=_pickerView;
    [self.stateTF setInputAccessoryView:toolBar];
    NSString * method=@"***************************?countryID=";
    NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",MAIN_URL,method,_countryId];
    NSURL *url_ac=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request_ac=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url_ac];
    [request_ac setValue:loginUser.acessTokenStr forHTTPHeaderField:@"access_token"];

   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request_ac queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:
 ^(NSURLResponse ac_response, NSData acData, NSError *connectionError) {
     if (connectionError)
     {
         NSLog(@"ERROR CONNECTING DATA FROM SERVER: %@", connectionError.localizedDescription);
     }
    else {            
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:acData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             [self parseStateListResult:acData];
         });
     }
 }];  
}
```

I want the response when i'm calling the state method. Based on state method response,i'm executing one task after calling [self statemethod]. That task need 'state method`responce. That task is executing before getting the data from state method.
The method exits after`NSURLConnection` line. I want to run the method asynchronously. Please help me.

Comment: "The compiler is leaving the method at the middile"?  What do you mean?

Comment: I'm calling `stateMethod` from `another method`. compiler will compile upto
 `NSURLConnection` line,after that it will exit from the method and executing some tasks which are there after the line i.e., [self stateMethod]; .Again compiler entering to this method and executing remaining lines (i.e., after `NSURLConnection`).

Comment: When you say "compiling" are you sure you don't mean "running".  You also seem confused about the concept of asynchronous operation as what you describe sounds right; i.e. the connection is established in the background and the completion handler is called when the response is received.

Comment: you are telling correct.It's happening at the time of app running only. I put debuggers to see the flow of application,at that time method will exit at the middle.

Comment: Where exactly is it exiting?

Comment: after `NSURLConnection`

Comment: But that is correct.  The connection will happen in a background thread and `stateMethod` will exit.

Comment: yes.It is correct but i want the response when i'm calling the `state method`. Based on `state method response`,i'm executing one task after calling `[self statemethod]`. That task need 'state method` responce.
That task is executing before getting the data from `state method`.

Comment: Then I believe you want `URLSessionDataTask`.  See [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/3244963-urlsession-tutorial-getting-started).  Although it's in Swift :-|

Comment: How to use `NSSessionDataTask`.

Comment: [Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34200617/299924) with some code in Objective-C.

Comment: `NSSessionDataTask` is also working same like `NSURLConnection`

Comment: I have got the output I want.I placed my task in `state method` after I got the Url responce by using condition.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm calling one method from another method.The method exits in the middile. After completing some tasks, it will run the remaining method.

It doesn't exit in the middle... the part after the `sendAsynchronousRequest` call is a completion handler. It's a separate block of code that you're passing into the request to run at a later time. Think of it as a parameter to the method, not part of the code of `stateMethod`.

With that in mind, you can see that `stateMethod` really does run to the end, because the last line of code in the method is the `sendAsyncronousRequest` call.

> Based on state method response, I'm executing one task after calling [self statemethod]. That task need `state` method responce. That task is executing before getting the data from state method. The method exits after `NSURLConnection` line. I want to run the method asynchronously.

Since you haven't given the name of the method that needs the response, let's just call it `foo`. Your problem is that the request is asynchronous, so `foo` gets called before the response is available. One way to handle that would be to put the call to `foo` inside the request's completion block, but you might not want to do that directly because `stateMethod` might be called from several places, only one of which subsequently calls `foo`. Instead, you might change `stateMethod` so that the caller can specify a completion block:

```
-(void)stateMethodWithCompletion:(nullable void (^)(NSURLResponse* response))stateCompletion {
    [self.pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    lblTitle.text=@"State";
    self.stateTF.text=@"";
    self.stateTF.inputView=_pickerView;
    [self.stateTF setInputAccessoryView:toolBar];
    NSString * method=@"***************************?countryID=";
    NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",MAIN_URL,method,_countryId];
    NSURL *url_ac=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request_ac=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url_ac];
    [request_ac setValue:loginUser.acessTokenStr forHTTPHeaderField:@"access_token"];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request_ac queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:
        ^(NSURLResponse ac_response, NSData acData, NSError *connectionError) {
        if (connectionError) {
             NSLog(@"ERROR CONNECTING DATA FROM SERVER: %@", connectionError.localizedDescription);
        }
        else {
            if (stateCompletion != nil) {
                stateCompletion(acResponse);
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:acData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                     [self parseStateListResult:acData];
                 });
        }
    }];  
}
```

That replaces the old `stateMethod`, but if you want to have a version that doesn't have the extra parameter you can always do that too:

```
-(void)stateMethod {
     [self stateMethodWithCompletion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I tried your code.It is also working same like before.

Comment: I have got the output I want.I placed my task in `state method` after I got the Url responce by using condition.Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, you might need or want to run the `stateCompletion` block on the main thread. If so, move the `if (stateCompletion != nil)...` block inside the block that gets dispatched to the main thread.