# unable to get header info form URL

Tags: swift, urlsession

I'm trying to get header information from distant URL with Swift 5 but it doesn't work. Could you help me please?

```swift
func getHeaderInformations (myUrl: URL) -> String {
    var content= ""
    var request = URLRequest(url: myUrl)
    request.httpMethod = "HEAD"

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {data, response, error in
        if let reponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            let contentType = reponse.allHeaderFields["Content-Type"]
            let contentLength = reponse.allHeaderFields["Content-Length"]
            content = String(describing: contentType) + "/" + String(describing: contentLength)
        }
    })
    task.resume()

    return content
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `task` is executed asynchronously, so your `getHeaderInformations` function exits before `content` is ever set. (The block that sets `content` will be called some time later when the network request completes. You should also check the `error` parameter passed into this block, because at the moment you'll never know if there is an error.

You basically have two options:

1. If you're not running on the main thread, you could convert `getHeaderInformations` to be synchronous. See [Can I somehow do a synchronous HTTP request via NSURLSession in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784315/can-i-somehow-do-a-synchronous-http-request-via-nsurlsession-in-swift) for how to do that.
2. Otherwise, you can convert the code that calls `getHeaderInformations` to also be asynchronous. To do that you would do something like the following.

Somewhere in your code you call `getHeaderInformations` and do something with the result.

```
 let header = getHeaderInformations(myUrl: someURL)
 // Do something with header...
```

Instead you rewrite `getHeaderInformation` to look like this:

```
func getHeaderInformations (myUrl: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (_ content: String, _ error: Error?) -> Void) -> Void {
    var request = URLRequest(url: myUrl)
    request.httpMethod = "HEAD"
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
        if let reponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse{
            let contentType = reponse.allHeaderFields["Content-Type"]
            let contentLength = reponse.allHeaderFields["Content-Length"]
            let content = String(describing: contentType) + "/" + String(describing: contentLength)
            completionHandler(content, error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

This adds a completion handler which will be called when the network request finishes. You would then alter the code that calls it to look like this:

```
    getHeaderInformations(myUrl: url)  { header, error in
        guard let unwrappedError = error else {
            // handle error
            return
        }
        // do something with header...
    }
```

Note: I'm using trailing closure syntax here which you did not use in your example. If you're not sure about it see [Trailing Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID102)

Comment: Thank you idz. I will try this and give you information if it works well.