# Download 1 file at a time using NSUrlSession in iOS

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am `downloading` multiple files using `NSUrlSession` in my `iOS` app. I want to download only one file at a time. But it is `downloading` multiple files at 1 time. Please suggest a way to download files one at a time.

I tried this property :

```
sessionConfiguration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1
```

But it also download multiple files if they are hosted on different servers.Please suggest a way to do this

Comment: NSUrlSession downloads files in the background and provides a completion handler when finished. You could download the next in the completion handler of the previous. However, why do you want to download one at a time. That will only be slower.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. **sync**: Daisy chain your requests from the `completionHandler`, triggering a new `NSURLSession` `resume` upon the completion or failure of the previous one.
2. **async**: Each operation must complete before the next one can start, and  *waits* until completion *signals* using a semaphore. The thread performing the scheduling of each `NSURLSession` `resume` will wait for that operation to complete. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21205992/218152

**sync/async clarification**

Neither of these options are suggesting to run your operations on the main thread: sync/async is merely referring to the background thread responsible for the scheduling.