# How to execute multiple NSURLSessionDataTask serially?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, nsurlsession, dispatch-async, nsurlsessiondatatask

In my case, when an App launches, I want to call 3 web APIs using `NSURLSessionDataTask`. I have 3 different methods for each API and inside each method, there is one `NSURLSessionDataTask`.

I want to shape my code in such a way that these 3 methods execute serially. Because, method B is depended on method A's response and method C is depended on method B's response. Each method also doing some database operation after getting API response. So, I need serial execution of `methodA`, `methodB` and `methodC`.

I know this is a logical thing but I want to use `dispatch_semaphore_t` or `dispatch_group_wait` but I have absolutely no clue on how I can use those in a conjuction with `NSURLSessionDataTask`.

I have tried with this:

```
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    [self syncA:^(BOOL success) {

        NSLog(@"syncA — Completed");
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    [self syncB:^(BOOL success) {

        NSLog(@"syncB — Completed");
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    [self syncC:^(BOOL success) {

        NSLog(@"syncC — Completed");
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    NSLog(@"************* END OF SYNC *************");
```

The above code is stuck on first method.

Comment: use NSOperationQueue for any serial operations.

Comment: Conceptually, `NSURLSession` is an operation queue !!!

Comment: look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198404/nsurlsession-with-nsblockoperation-and-queues

Comment: @Gagan_iOS This answer is no suitable approach for the OPs problem: first, you need three subclasses of NSOperation, and once you have those implemented, there's still no easy way to pass output data from Op1 to input to Op2 etc. This approach becomes that cumbersome and laborious, that it is undoable in practice.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper thanks for update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using those in main queue? Do not run the callback blocks in the same queue as dispatch_semaphore_wait, because dispatch_semaphore_wait will block the queue and the callback will not be executed, which will cause dead lock.