# Serial API Calls in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue

In my use case, I have a list and with every cell, there is a button to download a particular document. From the listing, they can click on any number of those buttons and the document has to be downloaded in the background but in a serial fashion. We will have to show some animation while downloading a particular cell document.

I've tried concurrent way and it's working fine but our main application is not able to handle such requests. So, we need to call those APIs sequential. Please let me know how we can do that.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Checkout - https://github.com/Heikowi/HWIFileDownload

Comment: @RTXGamer: Thanks for sharing but looks like it's making a parallel call I need sequential calls.

Comment: then create operations and add it in NSOperationQueue

Comment: Create custom NSOperation with callback upon download that notifies the cell about the download state, add those operations into `NSOperationQueue` with `maxConcurrentOperationCount=1`.

Comment: In particular see https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/226/ which goes deeply into the pattern Eugene mentions.

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk I tried maxConcurrentOperationCount but wasn't working.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to download serially? That can make it much slower. It’s generally better to handle the concurrency properly rather than forcing it to run serially. Don't fight the concurrent nature of networking, but rather work with it.

Comment: Also, when you say “in the background”, you are talking about making sure it continues to download even if the user leaves the app? E.g. a background `NSURLSessionConfiguration`? If so, notions of operation queues, or the like, are a complete non-starter.

Comment: @RobNapier - Readers should be aware that that “advanced operations” subclass of theirs has problems. It is not compatible with new Foundation class names and there were subtle minor little bugs buried in the code (discussed over in Apple’s forums). Apple has (rightly, IMHO) abandoned this `AdvancedOperation` subclass, going so far as to remove the links to the code. Conceptually it was a lovely idea, and the general observations referenced in the video are good, but their “advanced operation” implementation was problematic.

Comment: @Rob The software and utility we are using to download it works with sequential download only.

Comment: @Rob If the user leaves the app then it's fine if the file is not downloaded.

Comment: That’s too bad that your tool constrains you so badly, but it is what it is. Yep, then wrapping the download in an operation is a fine solution, and add it to a serial queue, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32322851/1271826.

Comment: @Rob I will try this solution. Thanks, Rob for helping me out.

Comment: Here is an Objective-C example of an asynchronous `NSOperation` custom subclass wrapping a `NSURLSessionDataTask`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21205992/1271826. The `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` could follow a similar pattern.